# ControlC doesn't stop .cmd script in Windows7 CMD window

Tags: windows-7, command-line, script, kill

I work with several Windows7-64 systems.  In all but one, typing ^C into a CMD window running a .cmd file, invariably (and expectedly) stops the program.  More importantly, if the .cmd script launched a computationally expensive Win32 application (call this HIGHCPU), apparantly the HIGHCPU application hears the ^C and exits, causing the .cmd script to exit.

The one special machine acts as if the HIGHCPU application never hears the ^C. That application simply continues to run.  If it finishes, or I kill its process, the .cmd script suddenly notices the ^C and asks if the script should be stopped.

On all machines, ^C acts like copy-selected-text in other contexts, just as you expect.

I have verified that if I launch the HIGHCPU application directly from the command line, that ^C immediately causes it to cease running and exit. Dark corner: HIGHCPU is a very complex assembly application; further, it catches ^C exceptions using the standard Win32 SEH, and that catch mechanism causes it to exit with nonzero status.

I get the impression that I have somehow configured Win7 on the one machine to treat ControlC for CMD windows special somehow.

Comment: Have you tried `Ctrl-Break`? A different keyboard? Just some basic troubleshooting before you spend hours going through settings looking for the proverbial needle...

Comment: A)IT IS NOT DOS. DOS is an OS hardly anybody uses anymore as they'd be 15-20 years out of date if they did. You are using the cmd prompt. B)if you type `break=on` (run that command) prior, does that help? it used to be a thing on old DOS systems.

Comment: @barlop: Thanks for the technical correction, and the corresponding edits.  If it isn't DOS (I agree), then I doubt `break=on` would work.  I tried it anyway, cheap experiment.   Output was an nothing but an extra blank line.  Tried running the script again; ^C still had no effect.

Comment: @JSanchez:  CTRL-break is heard by HIGHCPU program (which has a built-in "trace snapshot on CTRL-break" feature.  Sure enough, I get a trace from the HIGHCPU program, and it goes back to running. I note that ^C will cause a cmd script itself to quit running as soon as it gets control back from whatever it launches (the HIGHCPU program eventually finishes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like my HIGHCPU program wasn't explicitly "enabling ^C processing".  I added the following line:

```
SetConsoleCtrlHandler(NULL,FALSE); // enable ^C processing by our handler
```

before the already existing line in HIGHCPU's source program:

```
if(!SetConsoleCtrlHandler( (PHANDLER_ROUTINE) CtrlHandler, TRUE ) ) ...
```

and that seems to have cured the problem.

This MS page explains what the first call does:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I'm a little surprised at this; this ^C behavior has been "as expected" on every Windows system on which HIGHCPU has run since 1997 (Windows/NT).  This is the first time I had to do something to enable it.   The docs are not clear on the default behavior ("handles ^C/ignores ^C"); I half expect in Windows 7 somebody forgot to initialize the status of this bit, or changed how it got initialized.

Nonetheless, this seems to work on the "funny" Windows7 box.  I'll find out in a few days if it breaks behaviour elsewhere.